# Change the delimiter for Kafka destination in syslog-ng

Tags: apache-kafka, syslog-ng

I am using syslog-ng to send logs to Kafka.
By default, syslog-ng delimits all the data using ',' (comma).
Example:

```
2018/04/23 01:03:22,FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3,FIELD4
```

Is there a way to change the default delimiter and add some other special character as new delimiter? I would like to have something like:

```
2018/04/23 01:03:22*FIELD1*FIELD2*FIELD3*FIELD4
```

I believe, I may have to change the source code and re-compile it, to get this to work. Need some idea, where to make that change.

Comment: Why do you want to make this change? Are you trying to do something downstream in kafka based on this? And, have you looked at the syslog Kafka Connect connector as an alternative route? https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-syslog/ (c.f. https://www.confluent.io/blog/real-time-syslog-processing-apache-kafka-ksql-part-1-filtering)

Comment: Yes, I am trying to work with the syslog data in kafka. Having a custom delimiter will go a long way.

Comment: Have you looked at the syslog Kafka Connect connector as an alternative route? github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-syslog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [replace-delimiter template function of syslog-ng](https://syslog-ng.com/documents/html/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/reference-template-functions.html#template-function-replace-delimiter)

Comment: I am using a Kafka destination setting. Not sure, how do I use the replace-delimiter function in that config.
Here is the sample conf that I use:

`source s_514 {udp(port(514)); };
filter f_514 { message(".*MATCHPATTERN.*") };
destination kafka_514 { kafka(); };
log {source(s_514); filter(f_514); destination(kafka_514);};`

Comment: Something like this:
''' destination kafka_514 {kafka( template( $ISODATE $HOST $MSGHDR$(replace-delimiter "\t" ";" "${MESSAGE}")\n))}; ''' .

Comment: is it possible to have a multiple character delimiter, instead of single character one, in the `replace-delimiter` function? Just curious.

Comment: Hi, I think you can actually set a string as a delimiter, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: I tried using a string as a delimiter, couldn't get it to work. It was only fetching the first character of the string.

Comment: Well, in that case I'd suggest using a rewrite rule: https://syslog-ng.com/documents/html/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/rewrite-replace.html